# How to parse a function in a cpp file to access the loops

Tags: c++, parsing, gcc

I am working on a C++ project that has gcc as the defined compiler in the makefile. I cannot use a different compiler.
What I need to do is to parse through .cc files which override a particular method called behavior(), inherited from a parent class. This method does not have any arguments and always has void as the return type.
I need to find out the presence of loops (for, while and do-while) within this behavior() method and analyze them in various ways like finding the number of times they are executed etc. For example, let sample.h and sample.cc be the header and source files respectively.

```
                                sample.h
    class sample_class: public Base
    {
     ....;
     ....;
     void behavior(); //inherited from Base
    };

                                 sample.cc
    void sample_class::behavior()
    {
       ....;
       ....;
       int n=10;
       int count=0;
       int c=2;
       for(int x=0;x<n;x++)
       {
          count=count+n;       //LOOP1       
       } 
       while(int z<5)
       {
         c=c*5; //LOOP2
       } 
    }
```

What I want to do is to access the contents of for and while and be able to write something like:

```
    exec_time(behavior)=n*exec_time(LOOP1)+5*exec_time(LOOP2)
```

Could someone please guide me as to how I can do this while using GCC as the compiler?
Thank you very much for any help.

Comment: perhaps you can give an example of the function so that it is clear what is your problem and what is the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

"finding the number of times they are executed" - this (and only this) requirement necessarily requires runtime counting... you could either modify the relevant functions so they count how often they're called and save the call stack each time, then do some analysis on that output, or try using a profiling tool that already captures the same kind of information - perhaps [`gprof`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gprof), or even Quantify or valgrind.